# Centos config php on apache server

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I'm using a stand alone server (Not connected to the internet) which contains Apache server (httpd service) and php version 5.5 (installed with ./configure, make & make install).

This 2 applications were installed separately.

How can I config my Apache server to work with that php?

Unfortunately I can't use yum.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have apache and php already installed on your server. So you just need to configure apache to work with PHP.

1. Configure Apache to run PHP as a Module
   Add the following line in httpd.conf file if it's not already there,

   ```
   LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
   ```
2. Tell Apache to parse certain extensions as PHP

   ```
   <FilesMatch \.php$>
       SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
   </FilesMatch>
   ```
3. And restart apache (httpd) server,

   ```
   service httpd restart
   ```

refer [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where can I find the libphp5.so file?

Comment: in my case it is : `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so`

Comment: OK. I suppose that in my case it will be /etc/httpd/conf.d/modules/libphp5.so. But I have no file like this in there. How does this file get into the modules dir?  As I mentioned, I installed the 2 applications separately.

Comment: it could also be found here: `/usr/lib64/apache2/mod_php5.so`

Comment: How this file get into the apache dir if I didn't put it there? Is it there by default when the php was installed?

Comment: yes, by default it should be there after installation. Did you find this file?

Comment: Nop :(  Could not find that file. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.    I have httpd installed - root dir is under: /usr/lib64/httpd/.   I installed php 5.5.20 by calling **./configure** and then **make** and then **make install** without any params.  How does the httpd would get the libphp5.so file in this situation?

Comment: Yes. I did something wrong. Turns out that httpd has extension package named **httpd-devel** that contains apxs for the server. After installing it I needed to run **./configure ---with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs** and then **make** and **make install**. This does the job and creates the **libphp5.so** file. After that I just followed your instructions of adding the modules of the php to the apache server and it all worked!  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! Actually, by your own efforts you solved your problem.

Comment: When PHP 5.5 is installed in a CentOS 7 machine (from Remi's repo) it adds two separate files into Apache's configuration folders. One of this files, /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php.conf, contains the first code presented in the answer. The second file, /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf, contains the second code presented in the answer, plus some other lines of code. The best approach to know the exact content of a configuration file, in a situation like that, is doing a standard PHP installation in a virtualization environment, and take a look at the files placed there.